# What is the physical interpretation of the occurrence of a particular irreducible representation more than once?

Tags: group-representations

I am working on a problem about the crystal field splitting of the five-fold degenerate $d$ states. First, in a crystal field of $O$ point group symmetry, the five-fold degenerate $d$ states are split to a double degenerate $E$ state and a triple degenerate $T_2$ state. Moving further on a lower symmetry field of $D_2$, I worked out that the $T_2$ state is split to $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$ states. However, the $E$ state is split to two $A$ states. So I'm wondering what's the physical interpretation of  the two $A$ states. Are they degenerate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's a fact requiring a special physical interpretation. To understand my point think of another symmetry, e.g. $C_4$.

Both your and my example are commutative groups and all their irreps are unidimensional. Then a 5-degenerate state will split into 5 and there is no reason for residual degeneracy. Not even for a definite ratio of energy separation.

Actually we could think of different physical perturbations having the same symmetry, which could give rise to different patterns for the 5 split levels.